# ASP.Net Web Application Architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, web-services

I'm totally rewriting the question..

I'm new to ASP.Net, and trying to develop a website that is

```
- simple, but has many grids
- uesrs will update/delete/insert data on grids/tables through the website
```

Other facts would be:

```
- MS SQL Server 2008
- .Net Framework 4.0
- intranet 
- thin client 
- the website should be secure - no hole for sql injection etc. 
- 10 users
- Database tables are already defined
- no stored procedures are defined yet, but will be soon
- all database related functions will be done through stored procedures.
```

Can you please suggest which approach would be the best in my situation to communicate with the database securely. Entity Framework? LinqToSQL?, WCF? or ASP.Net Web Service?

I was thinking of Entity Framework as suggested below, but here are more questions related to EF:

```
1. Do I need WCF for EF? 
2. if DB tables are already structured, do I need to rebuild DB tables along with EF? 
3. is EF has more secure than ASP.Net Web Service? 
4. Functions are fully done by stored procedures, EF is a good choice?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you use a webservice?
You can check just communicate with the database through Enterprise Library, LINQ2SQL or Entity Framework

Comment: Thanks yohannesdedope, but I came up with more questions.. I restated my question. Can you please answer them?

Answer (score 0):

As architecture, I understand MVC, MVC2 or MVC3 frameworks that you can use to build your application.

As grids you may use MSSQL-side query paging or client side jQuery Datatables paging..

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework would be a great choice for this. You don't need any web services. EF 4 has a great thing called [Code First](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx), but in your case, your tables are done and I wouldn't suggest it. My recommendation would be for you would be to use [N-Tier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) architecture to design your site. Using N-Tier will maintain a separation of your data layer, business rules and your UI. Your data layer should be a separate class project that should only be accessed by your business rule layer. Your UI should never communicate with the data layer and only communicate with your business rule layer. If you want to go even further, program your site to an interface using something like [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) and [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/). This will ensure a true separation of data and UI.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simpliest way is to use [ASP.NET Dynamic Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee845452.aspx)